# Dynamically created class methods with additional data: data is being lost

Tags: ruby

I have a class, which is being dynamically extended with methods by another class. There is also some additional static info within those methods, e. g.:

```
class A
  # @b = B.new # in initialize
  def a
    puts @b.info[:data][__callee__]
  end
end

class B
  attr_reader :info
  @info = {:data => {:a => :method_name, …}} 

  def define_new_a name
    A.class_eval %Q(
      alias_method name, :a
    )
    @info[:data][name => :method_name]
  end

  define_new_a :a1
  define_new_a :a2
end
```

This alias method `:a1` relies on `@info` structure somehow (the code in `A` uses `B#info[:data]`). `@info` might be updated during execution as well. Everything works perfect until I call the `A.new` for the second (third, forth etc.) time. In such a case I have an already updated `A` class definition with methods, say, `:a1` and `:a2` (dynamically created,) but pure fresh instance of `B#info`.

*So, the question is:*

**TL;DNR** Let’s `class` definition is subject to change: there is a need to dynamically add methods *and* related data to it. Class instances are created within long run. Is there a way to make current class definition *synchronized* with the related data?

**Explanation:** *Where* am I supposed to store some *additional* information such as `info` structure to make it synchronized with current definition of `A` class? Making `B` a singleton is not an option as well as making `@@info` a class variable since it may actually differ between different instances of `A`. Actually, there are two classes introduced just to clarify the problem; there might be one class with both a) dynamically created methods and b) some additional info, those methods rely on. Singleton with a hash `instance ⇒ info` looks a bit superfluous and totally not elegant.

Another question is *is there a simple way to instantiate **fresh** version of a class*, without any dynamically created (during current long run) stuff?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think this is a perfect example for the daily WTF.

Comment: +1 to the Daily WTF suggestion. Methinks rephrase the question explaining what you tried to achieve. You'll get better answers -- all telling you to change your design.

Comment: Well, I rephrased the question in “TL;DNR” manner. To the DWTF voters: whether I could re-design the code I have it already had. Sometimes we need the non-obvious things to be done.

Answer (score 1):

When your class B gets loaded, you call `class_eval` twice on A to define two new methods.

So no: once B's definition is loaded, A's definition is irrevocably changed, and you can no longer access its original definition.

What you could do as a workaround is to wrap A into a class, so as to keep the original functionality intact:

```
class AFresh
  # Your code
end

class A < AFresh
  # Just inherit...
end
```

---

Btw: your design seems like a very broken variation of the dependency injection pattern. If it is, look into Symfony's Dependency Injection component for an excellent example of how to do this properly. And then look into Ruby's built-in Forwardable module.

Comment: The class inheritance is obvious workaround, though not the best solution. I appreciate the changes already made to the class; I need them. The only thing that breaks the fortune is that I need some additional related data to be accessible as well.

Comment: Per the two first comments on the question, you'll likely get better answers (all inviting you to change the design, imho) if you actually explain what you're trying to achieve. Fwiw, your design seems like a very broken variation of the dependency injection pattern. If it is, look into Symfony's Dependency Injection component for an excellent example of how to do this properly. And then look into Ruby's built-in Forwardable module.

Comment: Nope, it has nothing in common with dependency injection. I have troubles with the precise description of what am I planning to achieve, since there is post length limitation. In a couple of words: I am building a DSL for DSL (or if you’d prefer a meta-DSL.) There are new methods added to DSL handler dynamically _and_ some additional data within these methods.

Comment: Methinks you just made my point, tbh. Your DSL is A, and the class that adds functionality to create the actual DSL is B, I imagine? Assuming so, I'm at a loss as to why B could possibly be a *class* instead of a *module* that you simply include in the context of an object of class A...

Comment: Not exactly; I introduced `B` here just in case to make a problem vivid. The data I mentioned is created dynamically as well. When I create the new DSL method I need to store somewhere, say, it’s timestamp/canonical-name/whatever. E. g. whether I introduce `my_print :format_name` method I need to store `:format_name ⇒ real_format_string` to format by name.

Comment: Uh huh... And that might very well be the job of a formatter object, aka a dependency.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out back to DIP anyway. When I have just started the project, I was sure DPI is not suitable here; the world have changed since then, you know ;-) It is still inapplicable as is, but I think I have a clue now on how to screw it up.